# $\theta^Tx$ vs. $\sum_{j=1}^n\theta_j x_j$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm taking Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course on Coursera and there's a slide where he's discussing "vectorised" versions of different formula which execute much more efficiently than their iteratively defined functions.

One of the course lecture slides he defines a function $h(\theta)$ two different ways and defines them as equivalent, but I can't see how they are equal.

$h(\theta) = \sum_{j=1}^n\theta_j x_j$

and

$h(\theta) = \theta^Tx$

The main difference being that the first one reduces to a single value and the second one a row vector ($\theta$ originally being a column vector).

My two questions are:

1. Is he just skipping the step of summing over the row vector in $h(\theta)=\theta^Tx$ because he expects to use more vector operations in the future and does not need a single value?
2. Why do we need to transpose $\theta$? Is it just more convenient to have a row vector in some cases rather than a column vector?

I know any answer here will likely be working off of assumptions, but I'm guessing there are some sort of field best practices he might be working with.

Comment: Have you ever multiplied matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\theta$ and $x$ are both column-vectors.  So by multiplying matrices, we see that
$$
\theta^T x = \pmatrix{\theta_1 & \cdots & \theta_n}\pmatrix{x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n} = 
\theta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \theta_n x_n,
$$
which is exactly the sum we wanted.

Regarding your second question: there is no product (in this context) defined between two vectors of $\Bbb R^n$.  If we transpose the first vector however, we can get the inner-product (AKA dot-product) $\theta^Tx$ as illustrated above.

Interestingly, there is also an "outer-product" $\theta x^T$; note that this multiplication results in an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: If you are new to matrix-multiplication, see [this page](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html).  Look in particular at the "rows and columns" section.

Comment: I should have read the whole page. I didn't get to the part about 1 x 3 and 3 x 1 matrices. Some of the course material seem to indicate that "x" is a scalar in this case. An X would indicate a matrix.

Comment: @Breedly it is a common convention in this area that lowercase letters (such as $x$ and $\theta$) could refer to either to scalars or vectors (usually column-vectors).  Capital letters like $X$ are typically reserved for matrices that have more than one column.

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull, $\theta = (\theta_{1}, ... ,\theta_{n}) $ and $x = (x_{1},...,x_{n})$

Then $\theta^{T} \cdot x = \sum \theta_{j} x_{j}$

Are the same